How to execute poetry bandit tests without skipping B101?
I am new to poetry and pytest. We use poetry run bandit as part of our CI/CD process and it failed with the following error
>> Issue: [B101:assert_used] Use of assert detected. The enclosed code will be removed when compiling to optimised byte code.
   Severity: Low   Confidence: High
   CWE: CWE-703 (https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/703.html)
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.8/plugins/b101_assert_used.html
   Location: ./tests/test.py:21:4
21      assert config.PROJECT_NAME == "XYZ"

I see similar posts in SO and other links but they talk about skipping B101 or by skipping the entire tests directory
Instead I want to run the test case and fail the test case if assertion fails
Any help would be highly appreciated

I removed the python-poetry tag because the question is not related to Poetry, you would get the same issue if you removed Poetry from the equation. I removed the bandit tag because it is meant for a different tool called bandit (in the Ruby world).

Instead of using assert, you can use the pytest framework’s assert functionality, which is more robust and provides better error reporting. However, bandit will still flag it if it’s a plain assert statement, even in tests.
Skipping the B101 check or the entire tests directory is not recommended because it could allow potential security issues in non-test code to slip through. By using pytest or unittest, you adhere to best practices while keeping your codebase secure and robust.
try :
if config.PROJECT_NAME != "XYZ":
    pytest.fail(f"Expected 'XYZ' but got {config.PROJECT_NAME}")

